# ContentChildren for a ngContent with select

Tags: angular

I am trying to make some custom fields :

```
<app-form-field class="col-12 col-lg-6">
  <div formLabel>{{ 'i18n.Field.FirstName.Name' | translate }}</div>
  <app-input
    formInput
    required
  ></app-input>
  <div formError *ngIf="true" class="error-feedback">
    <small *ngIf="true">{{ 'i18n.Field.FirstName.Error.Required' | translate }}</small>
  </div>
</app-form-field>
```

now I can do this in my `app-form-field` to display the content at different places :

`<ng-content select="[formErrors]"></ng-content>`

but I would also like to get a ref of that content in my code :

I tried

```
@ContentChild('formError') formError: HTMLElement;

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
      console.log(this.formError);
  }
```

but it doesn't work.

I KNOW that I can make a directive, but I would like to try without if it 's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should declare formError as a template variable "#formError"

```
<app-form-field class="col-12 col-lg-6">
  <div formLabel>{{ 'i18n.Field.FirstName.Name' | translate }}</div>
  <app-input
    formInput
    required
  ></app-input>
  <div ( here --->) #formError *ngIf="true" class="error-feedback">
    <small *ngIf="true">{{ 'i18n.Field.FirstName.Error.Required' | translate }}</small>
  </div>
</app-form-field>
```

Comment: demo code here [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ij7ggx)